# How to fix open redirect in php?

Tags: php, security

I don't know much about php and i feel dumb asking this question here.
How can we fix open redirect issues in php? 
for example in the below code.

```
if($_GET["target"]) {
    $target =$_GET["target"];
    header("Location: $target");
}else {
    echo "No target!";
}
```

I am trying to redirect everything other than http://localhost:81/* to http://localhost:/81 and if i give input http://localhost:81/something comes it should be redirected as it is and all other should be redirected to http://localhost:81/ .

i tried changing header("Location: http://localhost:81/") but it is redirecting everything to http://localhost:81/
How can i edit or fix this to include no redirect for http://localhost:81/something ?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are saying. `$_GET` is an array that is set in url. `www.example.com?name=bob` would make `echo $_GET['name'] //bob` I can't see anything about the url "get" in your question

Answer (score 2):

Just take the $_GET['target'] value and check weather it is 'something' or not. If the value is other than 'something' then redirect them all to your desired location.

**Try this!**

```
if( isset( $_GET['target'] ) ) {
    $page = $_GET['target'];
    if( $page != 'something' ) {
        header("Location: Your url here");  // Change the text with your url
    }
}
```

Comment: Not trying to be mean but what if location is `0` (zero)? I think a isset is safer.

Comment: I don't see anything in the examples that shows that this is a question about  url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are variables for all the components of the URL available in the $_SERVER super global.

For example look at these variables:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo $_SERVER[['REQUEST_URI'];
```

There's also the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function that will take a url and return you an array with it broken into pieces for you.  Once you have it broken into pieces, your evaluation and redirection should be easy.

Comment: What i was asking was Locations on http:/  /localhost:81 / * must work. Please clarify me on what to be done.